# Install Linux on second hard drive (DUAL BOOT)

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, partitioning, bootloader

I want to install linux Mint on my second hard drive (1st: Windows 10).
I made 3 partitions: root, home and swap and installed it. However it doesn't boot into Linux and I get this error message: "Minimal BASH like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions."

I tried to select the second hard drive as well as the root partition on it as the boot loader but I end up with this error. Or do I have to use the windows boot loader from the other hard drive?

Comment: What error? Did you mean to include a screenshot perhaps?

Comment: [Minimal BASH-like line editing si supported. for the first word, TAB lists possible commands completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible completions of device/filename]

grub>

Comment: Most likely you installed grub on the wrong drive... Best way to do this is disconnect the Windows drive, install Linux Mint as stand-alone OS, then after verifying it works reconnect the Windows drive. Then use the BIOS one-time boot menu to select drive A or B to boot from. This is literally what I do with four drives installed.

Comment: okay and how do I do that?